# How to run docker-compose under WSL 2

Tags: docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

According to [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl-tech-preview/), using Docker under WSL v2 should be fairly simple:

1. Install WSL 2 (make sure all the preconditions are met);
2. Install Docker Desktop 2.2.0 or newer;
3. In Docker Settings > General enable 'Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS' and 'Enable the experimental WSL 2 based engine';
4. Make sure no Docker-related packages are installed in your Linux file system.

Once all this is done, I should be able to run `docker` or `docker-compose` commands from my Linux Terminal. But I'm not. I keep getting `Command 'docker' not found, but can be installed with sudo apt install docker.io'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

Did you check if the integration is enabled in Resources > WSL Integration as below?

[image: Docker Desktop Settings Snapshot]

For more details see: [Get started with Docker remote containers on WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers#install-docker-desktop)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28263078)

Comment: @Chris It's actually a link to the Stack imgur where the answerer uploaded their image, so it's not in danger of going away as long as Stack is here.  That said, the graphic should have at least been included inline, but that's a simple edit.

Comment: My config is like the image above but still getting `'docker-compose' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro.
`

Answer (score 5):

I just used `docker-compose.exe up` in a WSL2 Ubuntu terminal and it worked.
The `.exe` extension is basically needed in WSL2 to run a [Windows executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems).

Comment: an Awesome answer

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that wsl2 is enabled for your distro? Run this in Powershell

```
wsl -l -v
```

If your distro is not on WSL 2 then enable it like this.

```
wsl --set-version <Distro> 2
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and yes, my distro runs version 2. Daemon is exposed, WSL2 in docker is checked... Still, I'm getting the same error message

Answer (score 2):

1. Install docker and docker-compose.
2. Type in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo service docker start
   sudo service --status-all | grep '+'
   ```

Comment: You have typos and/or formatting issues: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I consider this a code-only answer. Please help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a platform for finding unpaid programmers. To do so please add an explanation of how this works and why it helps.

Comment: This doesn’t work on WSL2, as the system has not been booted with a regular systemd daemon.