# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on Windows with WSL2 and Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a Docker dev setup that works fine on Mac and Windows with Hyper-V but not on Windows with WSL2. When Python attempts to execute a `makedirs` command, we get a `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` error. For example, when attempting to make `/code/static`, we get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/static'
```

Similarly for Django's `makemigrations` command, which attempts to make a migrations directory at `/code/website/migrations` we get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/website/migrations'
```

But our [Dockerfile](https://github.com/makeabilitylab/makeabilitylabwebsite/blob/master/Dockerfile) clearly gives the `apache` user permission to the `/code/` folder. Here's the full Dockerfile:

```
# All Dockerfiles must start with a 'FROM' instruction, which specifies a base image
# See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format
# Note, some online sources say that you should put FROM django here (e.g., https://runnable.com/docker/python/dockerize-your-django-application)
# but, in fact, you should NOT do this according to the official docs (as this approach has been deprecated). 
# See: https://hub.docker.com/_/django/
FROM python:3.8

# Sometimes we get warnings about old pip, so take care of that here
RUN pip install --upgrade pip 

# See: https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-install-pip-in-a-Docker-container-using-a-Dockerfile
RUN apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install imagemagick ghostscript sqlite3

# The ENV instruction sets the environment variable <key> to the <value> in ENV <key> <value>. 
# See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement
# In this case, we are setting the stdout/stderr streams in Python to be unbuffered
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#Create a system user which we'll use later.
#We're using the 'apache' user since that's what we're trying to map
#outside the container -- it could be called anything, but apache is convenient
RUN useradd -u 48 apache
RUN groupmod -g 48 apache

# The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. 
# The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.
# See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run
RUN mkdir /code

# The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions 
# that follow it in the Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used 
# in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction. 
# See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir
WORKDIR /code

#COPY the requirements.txt into the docker container

# As an fyi: Layering RUN instructions and generating commits conforms to the core concepts 
# of Docker where commits are cheap and containers can be created from any point in an image’s history, much like source control.
# See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3.8 install -r requirements.txt

## TEMP related to: https://github.com/jonfroehlich/makeabilitylabwebsite/issues/866
#RUN pip install django-ckeditor

# Our local user needs write access to a website and static files
RUN chown -R apache /code/

# Despite the above, still getting permission errors on WSL2
# -- PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/static'
# -- PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/website/migrations'
# RUN chown apache:apache -R /code/

COPY . /code/

#Run the process as our local user:
USER apache

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh docker-entrypoint.sh
CMD ["/code/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

You can see the [full repo here](https://github.com/makeabilitylab/makeabilitylabwebsite) in case it's useful, including our Dockerfile, our docker-compose.yml, and our docker-entrypoint.sh script.

## Update

Based on @LiquidDeath's suggestion, I added the following to my Dockerfile right after the `RUN mkdir /code` statement.

```
RUN mkdir -p /code/static
RUN mkdir -p /code/website/migrations

RUN echo $(ls -al)

RUN echo $(ls -al /code)

RUN chmod -R 777 /code/static/
RUN chmod -R 777 /code/website/migrations/
```

And I checked that these dirs were indeed created by running the docker build command with `--progress=plain` and `--no-cache` flags.

However, I am still getting the same `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` problem once I actually run `docker-compose up`

```
 | ****************** STEP 1: docker-entrypoint.sh ************************
 | 1. Collecting static files
 | ******************************************
 | Traceback (most recent call last):
 |   File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
 |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
 |     utility.execute()
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
 |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
 |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
 |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 188, in handle
 |     collected = self.collect()
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 114, in collect
 |     handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 353, in copy_file
 |     self.storage.save(prefixed_path, source_file)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 49, in save
 |     return self._save(name, content)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 236, in _save
 |     os.makedirs(directory)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
 |     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
 |     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
 |     mkdir(name, mode)
 | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/code/static'
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66081700/2071807) was the solution in my case. "Enable integration with additional distros" then restart my laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That might be because in your Mac and Windows with Hyper-V, the containers are run with root privileges. But WSL2 is not allowing you to run as root. As a solution you can give necessary permissions(write/execute) to the directories/files.

In you docker file add the below lines

```
RUN chown -R apache /code/
COPY . /code/
RUN chmod -R 777 /code/static/
RUN chmod -R 777 /code/website/migrations/
```

777 gives full permission to owner, user and others, change this permission as per your requirement (refer to permissions in linux)

Comment: Right. I thought the same thing and tried that. Unfortunately, I still get the same problem. Thanks for responding!

Comment: @andicolortoo in your repo, i dont see /code/static and /code/website/migration folders. permission set are applied to existing folders, files. but in your case the newly created folders at run time (static, migration) aren't having write permissions, so static files and migrations are not added. create those folders in your local and create the image

Comment: I *think* I understood your recommendation. I tried it and updated my original post above to detail what happened. In short, same problem :( If I misunderstood something, please let me know. I've been banging my head on this for days. It's particularly frustrating because the Docker setup works great on Mac and Windows with Hyper-V.

Comment: If you see the error it clearly says permission error is raised while static collection runs mkdir. Instead of creating the directories via dockerfile, create those folders in your pc and build the image....please post the whoami, ls -la , pwd logs

Comment: This indeed worked! In my linux filesystem, I created the required dirs like `static` and `website/migrations`, then `chmod -R 777` to those dirs, then reran `docker-compose up` and it worked! I'm not yet sure if the chmod is necessary. I need to keep experimenting. Thanks for the help @LiquidDeath!

Comment: I accepted the answer. I'm still new to Stack Overflow and it didn't let me mark the full comment stream and interaction as the answer, just your original post. But hopefully other Stack Overflow users will read this whole interaction :)

Comment: @andicolortoo i will add the useful info in the comments to the answer later today. Thank you :)